# How to get only jsession value from the object?

Tags: vb.net

Below is my code

```
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = TryCast(requset.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
```

The result of responseFromServer is

> {"result":0,"jsession":"f0fcb39d-8cf5-47a3-ba85-f3cedbd26561"}

how to get only Jsession from responseFromServer?

Comment: The result from the server is obviously a json object. Google json and c#. There are standard ways for requesting json objects from a remote server and parsing them to get values. I would use with HttpClient to make the request and maybe use json.net to parse the json.

Comment: Thanks you it's working